# Why does the content <div> enlarge itself?

Tags: html, css

I've created you a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLk2p/).
When you delete the Errormessages the Contentdiv is in the right size, but If you add errormessages the bottomborder of the contentdiv enlarges himself and I don't know why.
Can you help me?

```
<div class='errormessagecontainer'>
 <div class='errormessage'>
  <span>Error</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Just add some of the innerdiv ('errormessage') into the errormessagecontainer.

Practically, I do this with a PHP Foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using position absolute instead, because its parent is also set to absolute this will work. Then you can position the errorcontainer relative to its parent. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLk2p/8/)

```
.errormessagecontainer{
position: absolute;
width: 20em;
border: 1px dashed rgb(255,0,0);
line-height: 2em;
bottom: 200px;
margin: 2px;
right: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but If you add errormessages the bottomborder of the contentdiv enlarges himself and I don't know why

Because that’s how `position:relative` *works* – it moves an element in regard to the position it would have without it, **and keep’s the original space required by the element reserved**.

Answer (score 0):

Set a max Height for the content container like this:

```
 max-height: 400px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add display:none; to .errormessagecontainer and set it to block when it's time to display an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**CSS**

```
.errormessagecontainer {
    border: 1px dashed #FF0000;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 25em;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin: 2px;
    position: relative;
    top: -228px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLk2p/10/)